# Calculating total time from HH:MM format

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, datetime-format

I'm given two strings from an API response like the following:

```
response = {
    startTime: '09:00 AM',
    endTime: '02:00 PM'
}
```

**Question:** How can I calculate the total time between the two?

Comment: Create two `Date` objects, then set year, month, day, to be the same (e.g., the current date) but change the hour and minutes to the start and end times. Finally you can just subtract one Date object from the other and you'll get the difference in milliseconds. Convert to whatever measure you deem appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Moment.js (https://momentjs.com/) to calculate this:

```
response = {
    startTime: '09:00 AM',
    endTime: '02:00 PM'
};

var momentStartTime = moment(response.startTime, 'hh:mm a');
var momentEndTime = moment(response.endTime, 'hh:mm a');

console.log('Time difference (minutes): ', momentEndTime.diff(momentStartTime, 'minutes'));

var html = 'Time difference output: <br/>';
html += 'Difference (hours): ' + momentEndTime.diff(momentStartTime, 'hours') + '<br/>';
html += 'Difference (minutes): ' + momentEndTime.diff(momentStartTime, 'minutes') + '<br/>';
html += 'Difference (seconds): ' + momentEndTime.diff(momentStartTime, 'seconds') + '<br/>';

$('#output').html(html);
```

I've created a JS Fiddle for this here:

https://jsfiddle.net/rrLdjjjp/1/